# How to add authentication token in header of `APIClient` in `django rest_framework test`

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-testing, django-unittest, oauth-provider

I am using `oauth2_provider` for my `rest_framework`. I am trying to write test case for my api. I have obtained an access token. But I am not able to authenticate user using `access token` in `APIClient`
I am looking to get this curl command work with `APIClient`.

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <your_access_token>" http://localhost:8000/api/v1/users/current/
```

I have tried

```
client.get('/api/v1/users/current/',  headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(self.access_token)})
```

and

```
client.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='Token ' + self.access_token)
```

Here is the part of snippet

```
from rest_framework.test import APIClient    
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase
....

class APITest(APITestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        ...
        self.client = APIClient()
        ...
        response = self.client.post('/api/v1/oauth2/token/', post_data)
        self.access_token = response.json()['access_token']

    def test_get_current_user(self):
        client.get('/api/v1/users/current/',  headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(self.access_token)})
```

I am getting response

```
<HttpResponseForbidden status_code=403, "text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Comment: Maybe you should checkout these for testing with DRF http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#authenticating  http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#forcing-authentication

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Since you are using `Authorization: Bearer` in curl, you should also use `client.credentials` with `Bearer` word instead of `Token`:

```
client.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='Bearer ' + self.access_token)
```

Comment: I have tried all sorts of combination with `headers={}` inside `client.get()` but forgot to try this.  I worked. Thank you

Comment: Where is this line placed, before : `client.get()` ?

Comment: Am getting this error :`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '`